# Actualizar tabla SQL con documento Excel

Tags: php, html, sql

Este problema me lo e encontrado muchas veces , y pienso hacer un proyecto que me solucione esto de la maneras mas modular y limpia posible (pero creo que lo primero es que se pueda xD)

Quiero perimero actualizar la tabla "nombres", esta tabla cuenta con los valores :

```
id nombre letra
1  stan   U
2  tony   A
3  steve  C
4  piter  S
```

si mi documento en excel es :

```
/ A      B  
1 stan   M
2 tony   I
3 steve  N
4 piter  V
```

al ejecutar una acion en algun boton o formulario con html y php , pueda actualizar el campo letra en la tabla "nombres" a

```
id nombre letra
1  stan   M
2  tony   I
3  steve  N
4  piter  V
```

saludos

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido tu lo que quieres es que desde tu libro Excel realices las consultas a tu base de datos. Para ello, puedes hacer uso de los macros en Excel y realizar una conexión en ODBC para realizar las consultas a tu DB SQL o realizar las modificaciones.

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta pero es mas bien desde un formulario o un boton pueda cargar my documento en excel y importar a la tabla SQL

Comment: Hola! Por lo que entiendo quieres subir un excel y modificar la base a partir de los datos de este. Si es así, yo utilizo https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ Es una librería que te permite el tratamiento de excels, tanto subidas como bajadas. En este caso sería obtener el excel que subes, tratar los datos y hacer la consulta sql pertinente. Un saludo.